# Error: Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_blocks": list of string required

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

While creating security groups, I keep getting the following error

> Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_blocks": list of string
>   required.

here is excerpt from **main.tf**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "sg_sagum" {
  name        = var.sg_sagum1
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.vpcname.id
  description = var.sg_sagum1
  tags = {
    Name = var.sg_sagum1
  }    
  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = [for s in var.sg_sagum_ports : {
      from_port = s.from_port
      to_port   = s.to_port
      desc = s.desc
      cidrs = s.cidr
    }]
    content {
      from_port   = ingress.value.from_port
      to_port     = ingress.value.to_port
      cidr_blocks = ingress.value.cidrs
      protocol    = "tcp"
      description = ingress.value.desc
    }
  }
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "sg_sagum_ports" {    
  description = "Ports to be opened on SAGUM SG"    
  type        = list(map(string))    
  default     = []  
  }
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```
sg_sagum_ports = [
  { from_port = "9000",
    to_port   = "9000",
    cidr      = "10.22.9.11/32"
    desc      = "SAGBPMS"
  }
]
```

> Inappropriate value for attribute "cidr_blocks": list of string
>   required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `terraform.tfvars` you need to change the `cidr` from

```
cidr      = "10.22.9.11/32"
```

to

```
cidr      = ["10.22.9.11/32"]
```